Count and check difference in timer countdown
I have timer countdown which starts from for example 04:00 (minutes:seconds).
And I want to check that timer is in diapason of 10 seconds.
I understand that need to convert time string to time and then check for diapason difference. But can not find a solution.
To convert string time I use moment:
moment('04:00', "mm:ss")
And then I need to check that timer is in diapason in 10 second around of 4 minutes. Because input timer can be 03:58
Let's say
time1 = '04:00'
time2 = '03:57'
Then I convert both to time and need to check that time2 is around in 10 seconds from time1

found a solution
const moment = require('moment')
    
const str1 = "04:00"
const str2 = "03:58"
const m1 = moment(str1, "mm:ss")
const m2 = moment(str2, "mm:ss")
console.log(`Difference is ${Math.abs(m2.diff(m1, 'seconds'))} seconds`)

